# Text with a dash in the cell but not in the formula bar (Excel)

Tags: excel

In cell E1 it says *You-Gov* but in the formula bar it says *YouGov*.
If I copy/paste values it stays the same, the formatting is *General*. Using `=CODE(MID($E$1,4,1))` I get a value of 173.
Any idea what is happening?

[image: You-Gov as opposed to YouGov]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have got here is called the "Soft Hyphen". It's purpose is to let the system know where a word may be broken, if needed, for display purposes.

[*"The HTML standard states that a hyphen character should be displayed at the end of the line where the break occurs if a line is broken at a soft hyphen. On the other hand, nothing is displayed if the line is not broken at a soft hyphen."*](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-soft-hyphens-to-properly-display-text/)

And that is exactly what is happening in Excel. It may appear in-cell but the formula-bar will only show the Soft Hyphen when the word it's used in is actually broken in the editor itself. To test this out, try to squeeze Excel and it's formula bar to a very narrow pane. You'll notice the Soft Hyphen will appear on-and-off depending if it's needed to be shown. It's rather funny that MS even mentioned the Soft Hyphen in their [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/character-set-128255) but it won't show in the matrix, probably for the same reason.

To solve your issue:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Select 'Replace'
- Search for: Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and type <kbd>0173</kbd> on the numpad.
- Replace with: <kbd>-</kbd> A normal hyphen.

Here is a fun little demonstration from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) full of "shy" hyphens. Resize the window to make them visible one by one:

*Margaret­Are­You­Grieving­Over­Goldengrove­Unleaving­Leaves­Like­The­Things­Of­Man­You­With­Your­Fresh­Thoughts­Care­For­Can­You­Ah­As­The­Heart­Grows­Older­It­Will­Come­To­Such­Sights­Colder­By­And­By­Nor­Spare­A­Sigh­Though­Worlds­Of­Wanwood­Leafmeal­Lie­And­Yet­You­Will­Weep­And­Know­Why­Now­No­Matter­Child­The­Name­Sorrows­Springs­Are­The­Same­Nor­Mouth­Had­No­Nor­Mind­Expressed­What­Heart­Heard­Of­Ghost­Guessed­It­Is­The­Blight­Man­Was­Born­For­It­Is­Margaret­You­Mourn­For*